# API: How do I delete a custom value?

Tags: api, custom-fields, developer

I may be blind but I can't see any api call to delete a custom value?!

CustomValue entity is missing a delete action.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please let me know what version of Civicrm are you using

Comment: sorry. current drupal 7, civi 4.6.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the ID of the row you want to delete and the custom group ID you can use `CRM_Core_BAO_CustomValue::deleteCustomValue`

```
$dao = CRM_Core_BAO_CustomGroup::class;
$groupID = CRM_Core_DAO::getFieldValue($dao, 'Emergency_Contacts', 'id', 'name');
CRM_Core_BAO_CustomValue::deleteCustomValue($id, $groupID);
```

Which deletes an entire row from the custom value table for this custom group.

Comment: It's not really what you asked for (an API call) but I couldn't find anything else and this helped me anyway.

Comment: Yeah, this could be useful. Too sad I don't remember for what exact reason I did ask this question :D But I know, it will be beneficious some day.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, you can't do this. If you try, you will get the notice:

> API (CustomValue, delete) does not exist (join the API team and
>   implement it!)

This is true for CiviCRM version 4.7.7, which is current at time of writing.

Comment: I just checked the latest version and you do have replace option in this version - just replace the custom value to the new value - you dont have to delete the row

Comment: Replace is not the same as delete. Delete implies there *is* no new value.

Comment: If that is the case - please create a new issue for the same which will get fixed in the future release - thanks

Comment: I don't have a separate question - I am answering the question here.

Answer (score 1):

API delete option for Custom value is missing in this version 
Please upgrade your Civicrm version to the latest version of Civicrm

please give a quick test  http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/api/explorer#explorer 
where you will find the delete action

Comment: Thank you. Although there is no such option in the linked demo-civicrm, I assume you're right and it's a version problem. Hope 4.7 will fix it – I'll upgrade in the next days.

Comment: That link is out of date. Also version 4.7.7 does not have the option to delete either, so this answer is wrong.

Comment: @moopet the answer was give to version civi 4.6.10 - if you need the same option for the latest if it is missing then please raise a issue

Comment: Your answer doesn't say anything about whether it appears in a newer version or not - your link is broken and from the look of it (d46.*) it's for the same version in the question comments.

Comment: Sorry, had to accept another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the value entered in a custom field, or an available option?

If the former, you should enter an empty string using `custom_value.create` api.

For the latter, use `option_value.delete` api.

Comment: Thanks. It's the former. But your solution does not make the contact to "not-have" that custom value. I meant, if I attach a set of a multiple records custom dataset to an entity, how to delete and detach this dataset, so that the contact appears as if it never had such custom data. At the moment a contact which gets such a dataset will forever be found when searching for contacts holding such datasets.